# How can I loop through a list of elements and toggle a class on them in jQuery, with a delay in between each toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to loop through a list of elements and toggle a class on each one (.active), changing this every 4 seconds. The active class will change the background color of the icon and display it's relevant text underneath.

So, the first element in my list will have the class of active by default (and it's info will be shown by default) and all other info for the other icons will be hidden, then after 4 secs I want to remove this class and add the class to the next element (thus changing it's background color and displaying it's text) and so on, looping back to the first element once the last element has toggled the class.

I am trying to use jquery each() to accomplish this but can't seem to get it to work.

```
<div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
                <div class="item wifi-icon"><i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="item plug-icon"><i class="fa fa-plug " aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="item suitcase-icon"><i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="item wheelchair-icon"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="item play-icon"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div id="info">
                <div id="wifi-text" class="perk-text ">
                        <h3>Free WiFi</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                </div>
                <div id="plug-text" class="perk-text ">
                        <h3>Power Sockets</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                </div>
                <div id="suitcase-text" class="perk-text ">
                        <h3>Luggage</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                </div>
                <div id="wheelchair-text" class="perk-text ">
                        <h3>Wheelchair Accessible</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                </div>
                <div id="play-text" class="perk-text ">
                        <h3>Onboard Entertainment</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

```
 .active {
    background-color:#74BDE9;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    let itemsLength = $('#inner > .item').length;
    let active = $('.active');
    let item = $('.fa');


    setInterval( function() {
        item.each( function(index) {
            if( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).next().addClass('active');
            }
        });     
    }, 4000);


    $('.perk-text').hide();

    if ( $('.fa-wifi').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('#wifi-text').show();
    };

    if ( $('.fa-plug').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('#plug-text').show();
    };

    if ( $('.fa-suitcase').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('#suitcase-text').show();
    };

    if ( $('.fa-wheelchair').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('#wheelchair-text').show();
    };

    if ( $('.fa-play').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('#play-text').show();
    };


});
```

Comment: Share the jquery code as well..

Comment: @chans jQuery code added thank you

Comment: Do you absolutely want Jquery or is plain javascript ok ?

Comment: @Weedoze vanilla JS would also work fine thank you

Comment: @Amit you can do this with a combination of `setInterval` and `toggleClass` in vanilla JS... not sure what the jQuery equivalent would be if you insist on not mixing jQuery with vanilla JS.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Can you please show me how?

Comment: Just discovered that jQuery has a toggleClass function. I've added an answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put the icon and the text in the same `<div>` ?

Comment: @Weedoze Yes, I can make this happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below a working example in vanilla JS

```js
const icons = document.getElementsByClassName("fa");
const texts = document.getElementsByClassName("perk-text");
Array.from(texts).forEach(textElement => {
  textElement.style.display = "none";
});

setInterval(() => {
  const iconsArray = Array.from(icons);
  const activeIconIndex = iconsArray.findIndex(icon => icon.classList.contains("active"));
  const nextActiveIndex = (activeIconIndex + 1) % iconsArray.length
  iconsArray[nextActiveIndex].classList.add("active");
  iconsArray[activeIconIndex].classList.remove("active");
  toggleText(iconsArray[nextActiveIndex].classList);
}, 4000);


function toggleText(activeIconClasses) {
  let textIdToActivate = "";
  switch (activeIconClasses[1]) {
    case "fa-wifi":
      textIdToActivate = "wifi-text";
      break;
    case "fa-plug":
      textIdToActivate = "plug-text";
      break;
    case "fa-suitcase":
      textIdToActivate = "suitcase-text";
      break;
    case "fa-wheelchair":
      textIdToActivate = "wheelchair-text";
      break;
  }
  Array.from(texts).forEach(textElement => {
    textElement.style.display = "none";
  });
  const textElement = document.getElementById(textIdToActivate);
  textElement.style.display = "block";


}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #74BDE9;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/fontawesome.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="item wifi-icon"><i class="active fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="item plug-icon"><i class="fa fa-plug " aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="item suitcase-icon"><i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="item wheelchair-icon"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <div id="wifi-text" class="perk-text ">
      <h3>Free WiFi</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    </div>
    <div id="plug-text" class="perk-text ">
      <h3>Power Sockets</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    </div>
    <div id="suitcase-text" class="perk-text ">
      <h3>Luggage</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    </div>
    <div id="wheelchair-text" class="perk-text ">
      <h3>Wheelchair Accessible</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` + `toggleClass` will do this for you. An example changing text colour every 2 seconds:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("#para").toggleClass("red")
}, 2000)
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="para">Hi there</p>
```

Comment: If you want to stop the loop at any point, assign the `setInterval` stuff to a variable and use `clearInterval(<VARIABLE>)`.